# SQL Server Group By result set is creating 2 seperate rows instead of 1 combined row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

Here is an example of my current table:

```
ProjectID   Level       Cost
---------   ---------   ---------  
101         LVL_1       1000.00
101         LVL_2       2500.00
102         LVL_1       1500.00
102         LVL_2       3000.00
103         LVL_2       1200.00
```

When I run the following query:

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID,
    CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_1'
         THEN Cost
         END AS Level1,
    CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_2'
         THEN Cost
         END AS Level2,
    SUM(Cost) 
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    Level,
    ProjectID
```

The result set that I am getting is as follows:

```
ProjectID   Level1      Level2      TotalCost
---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
101         1000.00     NULL        3500.00
101         NULL        2500.00     3500.00
102         1500.00     NULL        4500.00
102         NULL        3000.00     4500.00
103         NULL        1200.00     1200.00
```

However what I need back is this layout:

```
ProjectID   Level1      Level2      TotalCost
---------   ---------   ---------   ---------
101         1000.00     2500.00     3500.00
102         1500.00     3000.00     4500.00
103         NULL        1200.00     1200.00
```

I realise that the problem is the Group by, because I do not want to group by the levels, I only want to group by the ProjectID itself.
However I am not sure how to go about this as I am using the SUM function, any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Also just to note, my query is more complex than this. This is a simplified version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_1'
         THEN Cost ELSE 0
         END) AS Level1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_2'
         THEN Cost ELSE 0
         END) AS Level2,
    SUM(Cost) 
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 

    ProjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT 
    ProjectID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_1'
         THEN Cost
         END) AS Level1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_2'
         THEN Cost
         END) AS Level2,
    SUM(Cost) 
FROM 
    Table
GROUP BY 
    ProjectID
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT 
        [ProjectID]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] = 'LVL_1' THEN [TotalCost] END) as [Level1]
    ,   SUM(CASE WHEN [Level] = 'LVL_2' THEN [TotalCost] END) as [Level2]
    ,   SUM([TotalCost]) as TotalCost
FROM (

    SELECT 
            [ProjectID]
        ,   [Level]
        ,   SUM([Cost]) as TotalCost
    FROM 
        [Table]
    GROUP BY
            [ProjectID]
        ,   [Level]

    ) t
GROUP BY
        t.[ProjectID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope this helps you...

```
   SELECT 
        ProjectID,
        max(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_1'
             THEN Cost
             END) AS Level1,
        max(CASE WHEN Level = 'LVL_2'
             THEN Cost
             END) AS Level2,
        SUM(Cost) 
    FROM 
        Table
    GROUP BY 
        ProjectID
```